# Need to bound upper angle limit on 'detect features()', not just the lower limit. should be easy?

Tags: c++, cgal

When detecting features in polyhedral domain, we can set the lower bound FT as such:
domain.detect_features(80);

BUT, what I also need is an upper bound. For example I only want to detect as 'edges' between 85 and 95 degrees of triangle normals, not just 85 degrees and higher.

To restate, I only want to detect 'edges' for appx 90 deg +/- 5 deg.
It seems that this should be simple to have an upper bound as well as the lower bound FT.

This is kind of critical for my application where i'm combining organic with 'machine' cnc surfaces. Everything else is working great. If I can only have an upper bound then i'm good.
Any help or suggestions are super-appreciated. I'm kind of new to C++ but can figure things out.

edit: FYI here is a pic of a typical structure (triang surface) I'm working with. Fully manifold. Note that I just want the edges that are appx 90 deg.
[image: Hgon hyper-structure simple rectilinear]

Here is another image to explain. I only want appx. 90 deg edges to be 'detected'. Not any higher. Thus I'm needing an upper bound. The picture is from blender of the original manifold structure. I am tet-meshing this with CGAL.
[image: Edge angle highlight]

Comment: Please explain why you consider 90 degree angles as edges, but the even "sharper" edges of around 100 degrees are not edges. Examples might help to understand.

Comment: Hi thanks. The 'machine' regions of the structure have edges that are appx 90 deg... for example here the top and bottom plates. But, the hyper-mesh has angles much higher than 90, and I don't want them to be detected as edges.

Comment: Could you highlight an edge of noticable more than 90 degree in the image? I might misunderstand the definition of the angle we are talking about. That might be the reason for why I do not see anything which looks higher than 90 degrees. I spotted the edges which are likely the only part which as 90 degrees. But everything else looks more round, not sharper, than 90 degrees.

Comment: see the description of detect_features in cgal docs. There is only one parameter available which is a lower bound for the facet angle. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedral__mesh__domain__with__features__3.html#a5d8e66b530afb7f12e9dd7457e5be3c7

Comment: What you are showing seems to be blender to me, if that is true you should be able to zoom in on one part and highlight the edge which can serve as an example. Should you be restricted from showing a second image (not sure about your privileges), I will do so if it seems helpful to me.

Comment: I am editing the post to add the info.

Comment: Did you consider the possibilitiy that hte edges you are targeting have a much lower angle than 90 instead of much higher. I see many edges which I would describe has having approximately -120. Or are they considered to have 240?

Comment: It can be done by updating the function [`detect_sharp_edge()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__detect__features__grp.html#ga1e5e8ae3b4b8fc06270a50a48d92036d) and the API of `Mesh_3`. I suggest you open a [feature request](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues). Could you share the model? I'd like to see the edges that are detected as sharp and that you don't want. Basically you only want the base and top edges to be selected, right?

Comment: I think I see the edges now which indeed seem to be more than 90 degrees. But you  could still improve visibility with a zoom and the exact edge being highlighted. If this is blender please select the edge, i.e. make it orange. If it is not Blender do someting similar. I recommend this for the simple fact that only a precise highlight like that would have allowed me to immediatly see what it took me until now to spot. And now that I see them, I understand your otherwise clear question.

Comment: Thanks sloriot, yes I can share this example. Here is the OFF file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JMadiDzdbgaAqp5IFVIF29q5SMzfmnUR

Comment: Thanks Yunnosch, I'm away from blender/computer now I hope the visibility of the current figures and OFF file are sufficient.

Comment: Sloriot ... and yes, i'm just wanting to detect the edges that have appx 90 deg, which in this case are the base and top edges. In other more complex models/hyperstructures there could be more 90 deg edges than just top and bottom. I'm looking into detect_sharp_edges() docs thx.

Comment: responding to Sloriot... looked into detect_sharp_edges() and that also only has a lower FT bound parameter. Will open a feature request. This seems like a really good and likely easy thing to do. Having an upper bound is critical.

Comment: Adding an upper bound won't work as you expect for example due to those kind of elements: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2hsckcz.jpg + self-intersections. My recommendation would be to extract sharp edges using the aforementioned function (with 60 degree) and then build a graph a edges, call [`split_graph_into_polylines()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLRef.html#ga99ea6bf193f1194db5e523e713c82fb9) and then keep only the polylines that are significantly long enough. Then pass this filtered set of edges to the mesh domain as protected edges.

Comment: hmmm, I think I understand that. There might be some apparent self intersections as you showed in the jpg but those are probably just because i generated the OFF file very quickly without fully checking/smoothing it. I do see what you mean about extracting long enough polylines. Will look into that.

Comment: I don't exactly understand how to 'build a graph a edges' because I've never done that procedure; if it's easy for you to suggest a code line that would be great (otherwise any other's help?). In any case thanks I'll work on understanding that.

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sloriot/ab5cb4595a0c52a898e4df62480091c0) for example. I'm doing things with boundary edges of a triangle soup. You can do something similar with the sharp edges (using vertex instead of point index for example). The key part in the example is to build the adjacency list graph and to collect the polylines in the visitor. Another example of a visitor use [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/Surface_mesh_skeletonization_2simple_mcfskel_example_8cpp-example.html). HTH

Comment: Great thanks much, looking at gist.

Comment: Looked at gist, barely understand it but that's my inexperience. Is there a particular OFF file that would be ideal for me to test with? Perhaps the 'P.off' file that is in CGAL examples. I tried a plane of triangles but seems not importing properly or something.